# Mapping a Dto to an object with id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I am making an app using the ASP.Net Boilerplate framework and in my Domain layer I have a simple "Boss" entity. Creating and retrieving these entities from the database works fine but I can't get the "Update" to work. When map my "UpdateBossDto" to a Boss object and try to update it I get this error:

> $exception    {System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity
>   type 'Boss' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same
>   key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing
>   entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value
>   is attached. Consider using
>   'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
>   conflicting key values.

This error gets thrown in the BossManager class (I have removed the other methods for readability.

```
public class BossManager : DomainService, IBossManager
{
    private readonly IRepository<Boss> _repositoryBoss;         
    public BossManager(IRepository<Boss> repositoryBoss)
    {
        _repositoryBoss = repositoryBoss;
    }   
    public void Update(Boss entity)
    {
        _repositoryBoss.UpdateAsync(entity);
    } 
}
```

Here is my Update method in the BossAppService (i know getting the Id this way probably isn't great but right now I'm just desperate):

```
public void Update(UpdateBossDto updatedBoss)
{
    var boss = new Boss();
    updatedBoss.Id = _bossManager.GetBossIdByName(updatedBoss.Name);
    boss = ObjectMapper.Map<Boss>(updatedBoss);
    _bossManager.Update(boss);
}
```

And my UpdateDto class which holds the same attributes as the Boss class itself:

```
public class UpdateBossDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Hp { get; set; }
    public int CombatLvl { get; set; }
    public int MaxHit { get; set; }
    public string AttackStyle { get; set; }
    public string Weakness { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

How can I update the Boss object either with or without the Id? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a number of issues here. First, the id should be coming from the request URL, since it uniquely identifies the resource that's being modified. This also saves you from having to do silly things like `GetBossIdByName`. Not only does that require an unnecessary query, but it's prone to error. The id is your key for a reason: it's unique. Names are not. You could have multiple bosses with the same name. Additionally, your name columns are likely not indexed, which means such a query is vastly more inefficient. Then, with your id, you should be querying the corresponding `Boss` out of your database, and mapping *onto* this instance, not creating a new instance. Finally, save that same instance back to the database. Then, you will have no issues.

Comment: Thanks for the input! The way you describe it sounds like a logical way of setting up the Boss object for updating.

I have one more question though: Won't the error remain since I will still be updating an object with an Id that is already known in the database?

Comment: No. Your issue was attempting to track an object already being tracked. What happened is this. You creating an entirely new instance of a `Boss` outside of EF's object graph. Then, you looked up the id for the existing `Boss`, which caused EF to add that existing `Boss` instance to its object graph. Then, you assigned the id you retrieve to your not-tracked instance and finally attempt to add it as tracked. However, at that point, EF threw an exception because it is already tracking a `Boss` instance with the same id.